# How to combine two variables sampled from beta distributions?

Tags: r

My analysis will randomly sample values from pre-specified distributions for each parameter. I am using the `rdecision` package for this.

For example, in a simplified example where I have just two parameters:

```
v1 <- BetaModVar$new("Beta1", alpha = a1, beta = b1, units="")
v2 <- BetaModVar$new("Beta2", alpha = a2, beta = b2, units="")
```

I want to create
`v3 <- v1 + v2`

However, this is not possible given the nature of v1 and v2. How can I create v3? Essentially this would combine values randomly drawn from the respective distributions of v1 and v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question is about using the [rdecision](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rdecision/index.html) package, you can add the `v1` and `v2` model variables by creating `v3` as an expression model variable.

```
library(rdecision)
library(rlang)
a1 <- 2
b1 <- 2
a2 <- 20
b2 <- 20
# with model variables
v1 <- BetaModVar$new(description = "v1", units = "", alpha = a1, beta = b1)
v2 <- BetaModVar$new(description = "v2", units = "", alpha = a2, beta = b2)
v3 <- ExprModVar$new(description = "v3", units = "", quo = quo(v1 + v2))
print(v3$mu_hat())
print(v3$sigma_hat())
# with base R
V1 <- rbeta(1000, shape1 = a1, shape2 = b1)
V2 <- rbeta(1000, shape1 = a2, shape2 = b2)
V3 <- V1 + V2
print(mean(V3))
print(sd(V3))
```

Expression model variables can be used in decision analytic models in the same way as regular model variables whose uncertainty follows a particular distribution. But some of their properties (such as standard deviation) may be undefined, so expression model variables offer the `mu_hat` and `sigma_hat` methods to allow the mean and standard deviation to be estimated, if you want to summarise their distributions, as in the example above.